# Two types in the promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

In case of success, I have UserType returned in case of failure, I have ApiErrorType returned. How do I correctly specify the type of response result? I wanted to combine it all into one UserType, but it seems to me that this is wrong since these are different objects.

```
export type UserType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    accessToken: string;
};

export type ApiErrorType = {
    error: string;
    message: string;
    statusCode: number;
};

const getUser = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data: CredentialType): Promise<????????> => {
        try {
            const user: UserType = await original
                .post(`${isRegistration ? 'user/sign-up' : 'user/sign-in'}`, { json: data })
                .json();
            return user;
        } catch (error: any) {
            const errorJson: ApiErrorType = await error.response.json();
            return errorJson;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the correct type is

```
Promise<UserType | ApiErrorType>
```

Then you will have to make a type guard function to distinguish between the two objects.

```
const response = await getUser(...)
if('error' in response) {
 ... // here typescript will know that you are dealing with the ApiErrorType type
} else {
 ... // here typescript will know that you are dealing with the UserType type
}
```